# Как создать аннотацию, которая будет заменять setContentView?

Tags: android, аннотации, android-annotations

Хочу написать аннотацию, которая будет заменять метод `setContentView` в активностях, знаю, что есть библиотеки, которые уже реализовали это, но хочу написать сам.

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
public @interface ActivityLayout {
    @LayoutRes int layout();
}
```

Пока написал только это. Теперь нужно написать анализатор для этой аннотации или есть возможность определить метод в самой аннотации?

Comment: опишите как вы видите использование своей аннотации в коде ...

Comment: @ActivityLayout( layout = R.layout.main_activity) private BaseActivity extents Activity. Что-то вроде этого